# Show progress of file sending

Tags: android, progress-bar, file-transfer

Im sending files to my server from my android device, and would be great to get some feedback on how the file process is working out. For example in percentage.

Just that im leaving home for a couple of days and i would like to get right on it when i get back home becuase my time is running out. So would be great to return home with some descent tips right away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following link has exactly the codes that you are looking for. A sample application that shows the progress of downloading a file:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

Comment: Cheers mate, made my day so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
2. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Did'nt really answer my question since i don't have any problem accessing the UI Thread, I'm just novice about progress bars.